# Can I reset multiplayer level on Red Dead Redemption? 

Tags: red-dead-redemption

I've got to the top legend level in Red Dead Redemption (I have the super Zebra and that), but I really want to start again at level one some time.

Is it possible to do this without affecting my ranking on the multiplayer games like Grab The Bag?

Comment: If you can't reset your multi progress, you can always play on a new PSN profile...

Comment: pardon my ignorance, but how would i create a new profile?  would I have to create a new PS3 user and assign that to a new PSN account?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what you need to do.

Comment: So you can't copy your save to a usb on PS?

Answer (score 2):

I found on Xbox360 that using another save device will ensure a new Multiplayer character. They are not saved to the servers.

Comment: Back up your save first.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, **your multiplayer progress is saved locally** in a **file on your console**. Have a look for it in the Save Data section. **If you delete that, you should be back to the very first level** with no unlocked weapons or mounts.

Alternatively, **you can create a new user and PSN account** on your PS3 and start from scratch that way, which would mean **your original progress would still be intact** if you ever wanted to return to it.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, if you pass into legend your level, etc. gets reverted but you keep golden guns golden and your ranking in multiplayer games, even though they themselves get locked again until you level up once more.

Comment: yeah, but I've got to the very end, level 50 five times.  I do not think it gives me the option to pass into legend once more.

Comment: What system are you using?

Comment: ps3.  I coud have sworn I added the tag when I asked the question, but it seems to have disappeared now.

Comment: @Bagpuss: Questions that aren't specific to a particular platform, shouldn't be tagged as such - in this case, your Q seems valid for XBox owners too so it should not have a ps3 tag.

Answer (score -2):

Yeas. You need to delete the save of the same of the game in the game console file console saves.